# form submission in struts1 using javascript

Tags: javascript, struts

I am trying to submit  using javascript . Since I was not able to find  using "document.forms" so i used "document.getElementById" but now i am not able to assign action class to it .Can someone help me on this .

My code :

```
<html>

<head>
just to check javascript form submission
</head>

<body>

<script>

function formsubmission(value){
alert("i am here just before the form submission"+value);
document.forms["ashutosh"].submit();
alert("i am just after the form submission");
}

</script>

<form id="ashutosh" action="http://www.gmail.com">
<select onchange="javascript:formsubmission(this.formName)">
<option value="1">ashutosh</option>
<option value="2">ashutosh1</option>
<option value="3">ashutosh2</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>


</html>
```

Error :

```
Object #<HTMLElement> has no method 'submit'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://www.example.com">
            <select onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <option value="1">ashutosh</option>
                <option value="2">ashutosh1</option>
                <option value="3">ashutosh2</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/N4fxn/

Answer (score 1):

first error , this does not exist :

```
this.formName
```

"this" refers to select tag rather than the form, this.form refers to the form.

It seems like you are trying to get the form's name,

you get that by  form's object .name property, but only when you have name attribute defined

```
<form id="something" name="something">
```